# STM32 one timer for multiple push buttons

Tags: stm32, timer, interrupts

I have a small project where I set up a timer interrupt  to check the state of few buttons. Do I need to set up 1 timer per button or can I check 2 or 3 with 1 timer?

Comment: could you post your code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: you can check as many numbers of buttons as the timer interrupt frequency allows. But I believe you are missing to add more details to question. It's too vague! Is this code only for learning purpose or for some product?

Comment: Is there any other task that you want to execute when not checking for button states? Or you are simply waiting for some time period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use systick timer and a function(s) that at each systick interrupt increments a variable and compares with set time. Then it outputs a state.

Also you could make array of timers, that are processed at each systick interrupt.